# ImportError: No module named pipelines - Scrapy/PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, python-import, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an exe file from Scrapy project. I had to add tens of hidden imports to avoid errors but now I'm getting `ImportError: No module named pipelines` and I don't know what to do.

```
bot/
    engine_bot/
        engine_bot/
            spiders/
                __init__.py
                main_spider.py
            __init__.py
            items.py
            middlewares.py
            pipelines.py
            settings.py
            utils.py
        __init__.py
        helper.py
    main.py
    __init__.py
```

Main.py:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from engine_bot.engine_bot.spiders.main_spider import MainSpider


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess({'BOT_NAME':'engine_bot',
    'SPIDER_MODULES':['engine_bot.engine_bot.spiders'],
    'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':'engine_bot.engine_bot.spiders',
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY':False,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':0.20,
    'LOG_FILE':'scrapy.log',
    'LOG_LEVEL':'DEBUG',
    'ITEM_PIPELINES':{
    'engine_bot.engine_bot.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': 300,

    }
    })
    process.crawl(MainSpider)
    process.start()
```

**celery.log:**

```
2017-11-03 14:01:47 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-11-03 14:01:47 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
  File "site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 95, in crawl
  File "site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 77, in crawl
  File "site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 102, in _create_engine
  File "site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 70, in __init__
  File "site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
  File "site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
  File "site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
  File "site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named pipelines
```

PyInstaller CMD (lot of hidden imports, tried to add scrapy.pipelines)

> ```
> pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors  --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider
> ```
>
> --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.memdebug --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors 
>   --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.logstats --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader
>   --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors  --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider
>   --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors 
>   --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.telnet
>   --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors  --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter
>   --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.memusage --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader
>   --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors  --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider
>   --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.logstats --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader
>   --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors  --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider
>   --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.feedexport --hidden-import scrapy.spiderloader --hidden-import scrapy.statscollectors
>   --hidden-import scrapy.logformatter --hidden-import scrapy.extensions.closespider --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.corestats --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.spiderstate --hidden-import
>   scrapy.extensions.throttle --hidden-import scrapy.core.scheduler
>   --hidden-import scrapy.core.downloader --hidden-import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.decompression --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httperror --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats --hidden-import
>   scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats --hidden-import
>   scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth --hidden-import
>   scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror --hidden-import
>   scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite --hidden-import
>   scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer --hidden-import
>   scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength --hidden-import scrapy.pipelines
>   --hidden-import engine_bot.pipelines

I really don't know what to do, any advices?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this part of `Main.py`:

```
'ITEM_PIPELINES':{
    'engine_bot.engine_bot.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': 300,
}
```

According to provided project structure, it should read

```
'ITEM_PIPELINES':{
    'engine_bot.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': 300,
}
```

i.e. one `engine_bot` less in the path.

Comment: I tried it but without success.  main.py is in bot dir not engine_bot.

Comment: Yeah it is, but this module is loaded by Scrapy which reads it from configuration, which I thought should be relative to project dir. But obviously it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Change project strucutre from

```
bot/
    engine_bot/
        engine_bot/
            spiders/
                __init__.py
                main_spider.py
            __init__.py
            items.py
            middlewares.py
            pipelines.py
            settings.py
            utils.py
        __init__.py
        helper.py
    main.py
    __init__.py
```

To

```
bot/
    some_new_name/
        engine_bot/
            spiders/
                __init__.py
                main_spider.py
            __init__.py
            items.py
            middlewares.py
            pipelines.py
            settings.py
            utils.py
        __init__.py
        helper.py
    main.py
    __init__.py
```

See I renamed `engine_bot` to `some_new_name`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help too. The same error occures.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik did you also changed `'engine_bot.engine_bot.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': 300` to `'some_new_name.engine_bot.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline': 300`